# Python GUI changing the width of a line

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm programming a drawing application in a GUI canvas.
I need to make it possible for the user to change the Width of the line in the canvas by using a spinbox.

Answer (score 3):

You're not ever [getting the value](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/spinbox.htm#Tkinter.Spinbox.get-method) of the spinbox, or using the value to draw/redraw a line. Modify your `add_point()` function like so:

```
def add_point(self, event):
    #Use color[1] to get the second element in the color tuple.
    self.canvas.create_line(self.prev_x, self.prev_y, event.x, event.y, fill=color[1], width=self.spinbox1.get())
    self.prev_x = event.x
    self.prev_y = event.y
```

Now you can pick a color, draw a line, change the spinbox's value, and draw another line with a different thickness (`width`). See [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_line-method) for all the arguments you can pass to the `create_line()` method.

Comment: @RikkeG.Sørensen that's exactly what that one single change does. When I ran the full program with my change, I could click on the "choose color" button, my OS's color picker showed up, and I could draw lines by clicking and dragging. When I changed the spinbox from 1 to, say, 10, the line got much thicker. All you need to do is add `, width=self.spinbox1.get()` after `fill=color[1]` in the `self.canvas.create_line()` call.